# Is there ever any benefit/use for a void functor?

Tags: c++, void, functor

Is there ever any use for a functor with a `void` return type?

The only use I can think of is one that arguments passed in by non-constant reference, and does some sort of operation on them, and then gives it back to the calling program. But in such a situation, it seems a normal function is better (more concise I should say).

Is there any benefit to using a void functor?

Comment: `[](const T& t) { std::cout << t << std::endl; }`

Comment: @OP Think about `std::for_each`

Comment: Functions may modify global variables/state and still return `void`. *Not* saying that's a good idea, but it is possible.

Comment: You seem to distinguish between a "void function" and a "normal function" - that's really weird. A function is a function regardless of whether it returns `void`, `int` or some other type. Could you elaborate on that distinction you seem to make?

Comment: Consider the case of a `std::function<void()>` variable.  What if it's initialized using a capturing `lambda`?  That `lambda` can have almost any side effect  you wish regardless of the fact it accepts no args. and has a `void` return type.

Comment: Functors and functions don't need to return values.  They can perform processes (write buffers to files, write to hardware devices, generate signals, sort, etc.).

Comment: @JesperJuhl It's really common terminology for beginners to use. I don't understand it either. I almost never seem them talk about 'int functions' or 'double functions'...

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of uses for functors that do not return values (just as there are tons of uses for functions that do not return values). The first to spring to my mind involves a button in a graphical user interface (GUI). Typically, a GUI framework defines a way to designate a callback to be invoked when the button is clicked. In the frameworks I've looked at, this callback returns nothing – neither via a return value nor via an output parameter. If the framework was written for C, the callback is probably supplied as a function pointer. If the framework was written for C++, the callback is probably supplied as a function object (functor) for greater flexibility.

For example, [gtkmm](/questions/tagged/gtkmm) uses callbacks in the form of `sigc::slot` objects. [The documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-connecting-signal-handlers.html.en) affirms that these are "functors": *"A slot is an object which looks and feels like a function, but is actually an object. These are also known as function objects, or functors."* For the specific case of a button being clicked, the slot must match the prototype for [`Gtk::Button::signal_clicked()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Button.html#a2fa59b52db13af1de45b2745ea6d70c8), which happens to be `void function_name()`. That is, to get your button to do something, you use a functor that takes no parameters and that returns `void`. Useful.